# Why can't I get my modules to load from a directory in PSModulePath?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to install a PS module so that it can be imported from anywhere. I've added my install directory to the environment variable and that didn't work, so I tried putting my module in the PSCX directory since I know that one works. Below is the command line history that demonstrates the problem. Why doesn't "import-module foo" work here?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\pscx3\Pscx> $env:PSModulePath
C:\Users\chris\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell     Community Extensions\Pscx3\;C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

# There's my module; foo.psm1
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\pscx3\Pscx> dir *.psm1


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\pscx3\Pscx


Mode           LastWriteTime       Length Name
----           -------------       ------ ----
-a---     3/28/2013 10:37 AM           44 foo.psm1
-a---    10/20/2012  8:52 PM        19658 Pscx.psm1


# this works, as expected, so my PSModulePath seems correct.
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\pscx3\Pscx> import-module -force pscx

# I expect this to work since the module is in a PSModulePath directory... but it doesn't
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\pscx3\Pscx> import-module foo
import-module : The specified module 'foo' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ import-module foo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (foo:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

# Try again with the extension... nope.
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\pscx3\Pscx> import-module foo.psm1
import-module : The specified module 'foo.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ import-module foo.psm1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (foo.psm1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

# I can import the module if I give the path
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\pscx3\Pscx> import-module ./foo.psm1 -verbose:$true
VERBOSE: Importing function 'fooobar'.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create folder `foo` at this level:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\pscx3\foo
```

and put your `foo.ps1` file there.

Then you can call

```
import-module foo
```

Comment: Seems silly that you need a `foo` folder to contain the `foo.p*` file, but it works.